# Why isn't ALTER TABLE (adding a column) working in this SQL code?

Tags: sql, alter

Suppose I have a table (called `numbers`) like this

```
A B
1 3
4 4
5 5
```

I want to create a new column, `C`, which consists of values `A / B`. I.e. something that looks like:

```
A B C
1 3 0.33
4 4 1
5 5 1
```

I try this code but it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

`ALTER TABLE numbers ADD C VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL INSERT INTO numbers (C) VALUES (A / B)`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why you are storing a number in a varchar column?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As Gordon mentioned above, could you edit the question to include the database you are using and the error you are getting? I assume that your query has to be split in two, or in fact, three queries. The `alter table` and `insert` statements should normally be separated by a semicolon. The `NOT NULL` statement should be a separate query following the insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a generated column.  The syntax varies, depending on the database, but it is often something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE numbers ADD C VARCHAR(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (A / B);
```

Why you are doing an arithmetic operation and then storing the value as a string is a mystery to me, but it is allowed.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b214d466ef0275801683878f92c7683a) is a db<>fiddle, which happens to use MySQL.

Comment: Thank you. On a side note, do you know how to include multiple commands in a single query? For instance, I edited this table before to exclude values = 0 in column A using `SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE A != 0`, but if I try to combine this with your code to run in a single query (`SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE A != 0 ALTER TABLE numbers ADD C VARCHAR(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (A / B)`), it says there's a syntax error. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: `SELECT` is one command.  `ALTER TABLE` is another command.  They need to be separated by a semicolon in most databases.